# Use 3rd party packages in Node REPL

Tags: node.js, require, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to play with d3 (and successfully did earlier somehow?) in node. So I did

```
npm install -g d3
```

which works great. Let's check:

```
$ npm list -g d3
/usr/local/lib
└── d3@3.4.13
```

great. Let's make sure I have the package right:

```
$ grep name /usr/local/lib/node_modules/d3/package.json 
  "name": "d3",
```

Great. So try to require it:

```
$ node

 var d3 = require('d3');
 Error: Cannot find module 'd3'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at repl:1:10
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Nope! What gives?

Answer (score 2):

You can't `require()` globally installed modules by default (without mucking with special environment variables and such). If you instead do `npm install d3`, `require('d3')` should work from the REPL within the current working directory.

Comment: okay, so what happened the first time was I did it locally, before doing it globally like I wanted, then it "magically "worked.